# How to fix Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function mysql_pconnect()

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, xampp

I have the following issue am trying to run a CodeIgniter project but I get the following error when I access the the project via url on the browser am serving the project with xampp:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function mysql_pconnect() in 
 C:\xampp\htdocs\TaxiCMS\system\database\drivers\mysql\mysql_driver.php:91 Stack trace: 
#0 C:\xampp\htdocs\TaxiCMS\system\database\DB_driver.php(115): CI_DB_mysql_driver->db_pconnect() 
#1 C:\xampp\htdocs\TaxiCMS\system\database\DB.php(148): CI_DB_driver->initialize() 
#2 C:\xampp\htdocs\TaxiCMS\system\core\Loader.php(346): DB(Array, NULL) 
#3 C:\xampp\htdocs\TaxiCMS\system\core\Loader.php(1171): CI_Loader->database() 
#4 C:\xampp\htdocs\TaxiCMS\system\core\Loader.php(152): CI_Loader->_ci_autoloader() 
#5 C:\xampp\htdocs\TaxiCMS\system\core\Controller.php(51): CI_Loader->initialize() 
#6 C:\xampp\htdocs\TaxiCMS\application\controllers\admin.php(10): CI_Controller->__construct() 
#7 C:\xampp\htdocs\TaxiCMS\system\core\CodeIgniter.php(308): Admin->__construct() 
#8 C:\xampp\htdocs\TaxiCMS\index.php(202): require_once('C:\\xampp\\htdocs...') 
#9 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\TaxiCMS\system\database\drivers\mysql\mysql_driver.php on line 91
```

Comment: show your database.php from config folder

Answer (score 3):

The database config folder was as follows

```
    <?php 
.....
    $db["default"]["hostname"] = "localhost";
    $db["default"]["username"] = "root";
    $db["default"]["password"] = "";
    //$db["default"]["database"] ="test";
    $db["default"]["database"] ="test;
    $db["default"]["dbdriver"] = 'mysql';
    $db["default"]["dbprefix"] = "";
    $db["default"]["pconnect"] = TRUE;
    $db["default"]["db_debug"] = FALSE;
    $db["default"]["cache_on"] = FALSE;
    $db["default"]["cachedir"] = "";
....
```

The solution was just to change

`$db['default']['dbdriver'] = 'mysql';`

**to**

`$db['default']['dbdriver'] = 'mysqli';`

Comment: Then you have PHP 7, where the mysql client was removed